# React getting empty array when posting axios to reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, reducers

I am having problem where I am not getting data back in action.payload.data when using axios post method.

On Sign up page I am firing action when submitting form

```
  onSubmit(props) {
    this.props.signUpUser(props)
      .then(() => {
      this.context.router.push('/');
      });
  }
```

In the action files

```
export function signUpUser(props) {
    console.log("props", props);
    const request = axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
        method: 'post',
        data: props
    })
```

When I console.log the props it shows

```
 props Object {username: "11", email: "1", password: "1", passwordConfirmation: "1"}
```

But when I console log it on the reducer.
I get the data inside object.config.adapter instead object.data.

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SIGN_UP_USER:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return action.payload.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[image]

I can see that data goes in fine when I check my database but not sure why I get empty array when I call payload.data. My goal is to store the registered user's information to reducer so I display their information after they have registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that your API is returning any data? It looks to me like your code is working as expected, but your API isn't returning any data. I don't think this is a react/redux issue.

The `data` object you are referring to, 
`{username: "11", email: "1", password: "1", passwordConfirmation: "1"}`
is the data that is in the body in the post TO the API.

You should take a look at your API/user controller to see why it is not returning data in its response.

Comment: So I tested this on postman when I post say 'api/users the result was empty [] but when I called get 'api/users I do get the test I posted. So not sure if you are suppose to get empty array or actual data you posted.
I console logged this in the node and I get empty array.  It is weird that I am still getting data registered to sql though.

Comment: My guess is that the query in your controller is incorrect, so the query returns no results, and thus an empty data array in the API response.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you dispatching the action?

Change your promise

```
.then((data) => {
      dispatch({type:'SIGN_UP_USER', payload:data})//you have to pass dispatch to the function call
      this.context.router.push('/');
      });
  }
```

You have to set it as property value.

try

```
return Object.assign(state, {data:action.payload.data})
```

or with es6 syntax

```
return { ...state, data:action.payload.data }
```

Comment: I am still getting empty data.
I am console logging it to check before I use the state.
So I did console.log({...state, data: action.payload.data} still gives me empty array.

Comment: So action is imported by: import { signUpUser } from '../actions/index';

Comment: function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {  
  return bindActionCreators({ signUpUser }, dispatch);
}

Comment: `export default reduxForm({  
  form: 'PostsNewForm',  
  fields: ['username', 'email', 'password', 'passwordConfirmation'],
  validate  
}, null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp);  `